# Robot FrameWork - Get Current Date Issue - No keyword with name '=' found

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, robotframework

I'm trying to update a column on one Excel File with the Current Time.

To accomplish it, I'm using `Get Current Date` keyword from `DateTime` Library and store it to the scalar `${datetime}` on the script below

```
 *** Settings ***
 Default Tags      Download_File
 Library           SeleniumLibrary
 Library           ExcelLibrary
 Resource          Userdefinedkeywords.txt
 Library           DateTime

 Run Keyword If    ${countt}>0    Run Keywords    Click Element    xpath://[@id="fileSubmit"]/div[1]/img
    ...    AND    Open Excel    D:\\RPA\\Demo\\Excelx.xls
    ...    AND    Put String To Cell    Test    2    ${countd}    ZIP FILE
    ...    AND    Save Excel    D:\\RPA\\Demo\\Excelx_DONE.xls
    ...    ELSE IF    ${countt2}>0    Run Keywords    Click Element    xpath://*[@id="plsAttachGrid_0_1"]/img
    ...    AND    ${datetime}=    Get Current Date
    ...    AND    Open Excel    D:\\RPA\\Demo\\Excelx.xls
    ...    AND    Put String To Cell    Test    2    ${countd}    SINGLE FILE
    ...    AND    Put String To Cell    Test    3    ${countd}    ${datetime}
    ...    AND    Save Excel    D:\\RPA\\Demo\\Excelx_DONE.xls
    ...    ELSE    Run Keywords    Open Excel    D:\\RPA\\Demo\\Excelx.xls
    ...    AND    Put String To Cell    Test    2    ${countd}    NO FILE
 ${countd}=    Evaluate    ${countd}+${1}
```

I'm getting the following error:

`FAIL : No keyword with name '=' found.`

When the part of the code is run:

`...    AND    ${datetime}=    Get Current Date`

What is wrong on the code?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do variable assignment inside Run Keyword If - it only runs keywords, and this what the framework throws an error for.

```
Run Keyword If    ${countt}>0    Run Keywords    Click Element    xpath://[@id="fileSubmit"]/div[1]/img
# skipped lines
    ...    AND    ${datetime}=    Get Current Date
    ...    AND    # skipped lines
```

When it gets to that line, it tries running a keyword `${datetime}=` with argument "Get Current Date", and fails.